# Trouble dispatching async action from within actions creator

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to start a loading spinner when an image uploads as part of a form, and stop it when a reference to the image is saved in Firebase.

This function in my Actions.js file returns the input from a given form field:

`export const formUpdate = ({ prop, value }) => {
  alert('update')
  return {
    type: FORM_UPDATE,
    payload: { prop, value }
  };
};`

With Connect, I use `formUpdate` to store values for different form fields in my Form.js component - this works fine.

I use a separate function in Actions.js to handle the image upload, and once uploaded, I call this function to save a reference in Firebase:

`` export const saveImageReference = (downloadUrl, sessionId) => {
  const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
  firebase
    .database()
    .ref(`users/${currentUser.uid}/images`)
    .push({
      imageId: sessionId,
      imageUrl: downloadUrl
    })
    .then(formUpdate({ prop: 'loading', value: false }));
}; ``

I'm trying to get my form to show a loading spinner during upload. To do this, I'm using `formUpdate` at the end of `saveImageReference` to dispatch a `loading` prop. However, this isn't working.

`formUpdate` executes as part of the `.then()` block - I see the alert to confirm this - but no data makes it to the Form component.

I've also tried using a different prop (for example 'name') to see if it updates the form field, but nothing happens.

I have `redux-thunk` working properly - I use a similar approach to show a spinner in my login form - but this action doesn't seem to want to play ball.

If it helps, here's `mapStateToProps` from my Form component:

```
  const { name, location, loading } = state.testForm;
  return {
    loading,
    name,
    activity
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { formUpdate, uploadImage }
)(Form);
```

**Update**

Here's the uploadImage code based on azundo's answer. This doesn't execute:

```
export const uploadImage = (
  uri,
  mime = 'application/octet-stream'
) => dispatch => {
  const { Blob } = RNFetchBlob.polyfill;
  window.XMLHttpRequest = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.XMLHttpRequest;
  window.Blob = Blob;

  const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();

  console.log('Starting upload action...');
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('in promise 1');
    const uploadUri = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? uri.replace('file://', '') : uri;
    const sessionId = new Date().getTime();
    // create a reference in firebase storage for the file
    let uploadBlob = null;
    const imageRef = firebase
      .storage()
      .ref(`user/${currentUser.uid}/images`)
      .child(`image_${sessionId}`);

    // encode data with base64 before upload
    RNFetchBlob.fs
      .readFile(uploadUri, 'base64')
      .then(data => {
        console.log('Encoding image...');
        return RNFetchBlob.polyfill.Blob.build(data, {
          type: `${mime};BASE64`
        });
      })
      // put blob into storage reference
      .then(blob => {
        uploadBlob = blob;
        console.log('uploading...');
        return imageRef.put(blob, { contentType: mime });
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Getting download URL...');
        uploadBlob.close();
        return imageRef.getDownloadURL();
      })
      .then(url => {
        console.log('Saving reference...');
        // setLoading();
        resolve(url);
        saveImageReference(url, sessionId);
      })
      .then(() => {
        dispatch(formUpdate({ prop: 'loading', value: false }));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        reject(error);
      });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much investigation, I solved the issue. I moved `saveImageReference()` from Actions.js to my component:

```
addImage = () => {
    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(response => {
      if (!response.didCancel) {
        // shows modal with a form for user to select an image and add metadata
        this.setState({ showModal: true });

        // set the loading spinner in the form to show image is uploading
        this.props.formUpdate({ prop: 'loading', value: true });

        // takes the selected image and invokes uploadImage
        uploadImage(response.uri).then(url => {

        // once image is uploaded, generate sessionId in the component, and invoke saveImageReference
          const sessionId = new Date().getTime();
          this.props.saveImageReference(url, sessionId);
        });
      }
    });
  };
```

The `uploadImage()` action creator resolves with the URL of a successfully uploaded image, which `saveImageReference()` uses to create the reference.

Once that reference is saved, `saveImageReference()` dispatches a dedicated action to set loading to false. Here's the contents of Actions.js:

```
export const uploadImage = (uri, mime = 'application/octet-stream') => {
  const { Blob } = RNFetchBlob.polyfill;
  window.XMLHttpRequest = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.XMLHttpRequest;
  window.Blob = Blob;

  const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();

  console.log('Starting upload action...');
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('in promise');
    const uploadUri = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? uri.replace('file://', '') : uri;
    const sessionId = new Date().getTime();
    // create a reference in firebase storage for the file
    let uploadBlob = null;
    const imageRef = firebase
      .storage()
      .ref(`user/${currentUser.uid}/images`)
      .child(`image_${sessionId}`);

    // encode data with base64 before upload
    RNFetchBlob.fs
      .readFile(uploadUri, 'base64')
      .then(data => {
        console.log('Encoding image...');
        return RNFetchBlob.polyfill.Blob.build(data, {
          type: `${mime};BASE64`
        });
      })
      // put blob into storage reference
      .then(blob => {
        uploadBlob = blob;
        console.log('uploading...');
        return imageRef.put(blob, { contentType: mime });
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Getting download URL...');
        uploadBlob.close();
        return imageRef.getDownloadURL();
      })
      .then(url => {
        resolve(url, sessionId);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        reject(error);
      });
  });
};

export const saveImageReference = (downloadUrl, sessionId) => {
  const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
  console.log('Saving reference!');
  return dispatch => {
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref(`users/${currentUser.uid}/images`)
      .push({
        imageId: sessionId,
        imageUrl: downloadUrl
      })
      .then(ref => {
        console.log(ref.key);
        dispatch(imageUploadComplete());
      });
  };
};

const imageUploadComplete = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    return dispatch({
      type: IMAGE_CREATE,
      payload: false
    });
  };
};
```

No matter what I tried, I couldn't dispatch another action from within `saveImageReference()` - introducing `return dispatch` would freeze the flow, and without it I'd get `dispatch is not defined`.

Invoking this at a component level, using `this.props.saveImageReference()` solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you've described, the `formUpdate` call in `saveImageReference` is not actually dispatching your action, it's just calling the bare `formUpdate` function which simply returns the plain action object. You'll need to find some way to actually get that action dispatched.

Assuming `uploadImage` is a `redux-thunk` action I would recommend keeping the knowledge of the action dispatch out of the `saveImageReference` function and instead dispatch from `uploadImage`:

```
export const saveImageReference = (downloadUrl, sessionId) => {
  const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
  // note that we are now returning the firebase promise here
  return firebase
    .database()
    .ref(`users/${currentUser.uid}/images`)
    .push({
      imageId: sessionId,
      imageUrl: downloadUrl
    });
};

const uploadImage = (arg1, arg2) => dispatch => {
  // other upload code here prior to calling the firebase function...
  saveImageReference(downloadUrl, sessionId).then(() => {
    dispatch(formUpdate({prop: 'loading', value: false}));
  });

})
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! I tried following your suggestion, and added the code to my original post. It seems that introducing `dispatch` to `uploadImage` stops the function from running - I don't see any of the logs.

Comment: Can you share how you're configuring your store and how `uploadImage` is being called? If `redux-thunk` is set up and `uploadImage` is being dispatched to the store at the very least your `Starting upload action...` should be called. Also in your updated code make sure you have `return saveImageReference(...)` so the next `then` block doesn't execute until `saveImageReference` resolves.

Comment: I've solved the problem now - thanks for your help. For visibility, I'll do my best to explain how I fixed it in a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to render loader, when you await for an async operation. You could use suspense.

This would be a better option.

```js
const OtherComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./OtherComponent'));

function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <React.Suspense fallback={<Spinner />}>
      <div>
        <OtherComponent />
      </div>
    </React.Suspense>
  );
}
```